# Ensuring that a symmetric matrix with nonnegative elements is positive semidefinite

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

I have the following matrix $A$:

- symmetric
- all positive and/or zero values
- the main diagonal is all the same value, $x$.

To ensure that the matrix $A$, is positive semidefinite, must I only ensure that $x \geq 0$?  It seems correct from my thinking, but wanted to make sure. Thanks.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoublyNonnegativeMatrix.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not sufficient to have positive diagonal entries.
To see this, consider the matrix 
$$
A=\pmatrix{1& 10\\10& 1}.
$$
It has the negative eigenvalue $-9$ to the eigenvector 
$$
v=\pmatrix{1\\-1},
$$and is thus not positive semi-definite.

Answer (score 8):

Note however that a diagonally dominant symmetric matrix is positive semi definite.

In your case it is sufficient to add the condition $x \ge \sum_{j\neq i} A_{ij}, i\neq j$ to ensure $A$ to be positive semi definite.

Comment: Why does it suffice for $x\ge A_{ij}$?  I would appreciate a reference for this if you have one.

Comment: @user3281410 The wikipedia article states this property for Hermitian diagonally dominant matrices, so it applies for real symmetric matrices as well : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix

Comment: I believe you mean to say $x\ge \sum_{j\neq i}^{}A_{ij}$ for all $i$, not just $x\ge A_{ij}$ for all $i\neq j$.  There are symmetric, matrices with nonnegative entries such that the entries on the diagonal are all the same (denoted $x$) and satisfy $x \ge A_{ij}$ but $A$ is not positive semidefinite.  See the first answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2669941/is-a-doubly-stochastic-matrix-positive-semidefinite-if-the-maximum-of-each-row-o

Comment: @user3281410 Yep sorry I really meant $x \ge \sum_j A_{ij}, i\neq j$. I've updated the answer !

Comment: @Tool is the converse statement true? If I have a positive semidefinite matrix, can I say that it must also be diagonally dominant with nonnegative real entries on the diagonal?