# Conditions on off-diagonal elements of a 2x2 density matrix

Tags: matrices, physics, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

This comes from a physical context (see [density matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix)), but I don't believe that is crucial to the problem.

Suppose I have the following $2$ x $2$ Hermitian matrix 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b  \\
    b^* & c  \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
with the conditions that $Tr[A]=1$. Assuming I know the values of $a$ and $c$, what values of $b$ ensure that the resulting matrix is positive semidefinite?

I have seen from [Ensuring that a symmetric matrix with nonnegative elements is positive semidefinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270966/ensuring-that-a-symmetric-matrix-with-nonnegative-elements-is-positive-semidefin) that it sufficient to have a diagonally dominant matrix with nonnegative terms on the diagonal, but I'm still wondering if I can find a necessary and sufficient condition to ensure I have a proper density matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b  \\
    b^* & 1-a  \\
    \end{pmatrix}.$$
Its eigenvalues are the soultions of the characteristic equation
$0 = \det(A-\lambda E) = (a-\lambda)(1-a-\lambda)-|b|^2 = \lambda^2 - \lambda + a(1-a)-|b|^2 = \lambda^2 - \lambda + \det A. $

Both roots are non-negative iff $\det A\geqslant 0$, i.e., $\sqrt{a(1-a)}\geqslant|b|$.

Finally, the matrix is positive semidefinite when all eigenvalues are non-negative.